# One MouseListener for many JLabel components

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

I have 17 `JLabel` components and I want to add same handler for all these labels. Actually I have have to increase the size of the label when mouse hovers over it. Code is here:

```
private void lblBackupMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
 lblBackup.setSize(lblBackup.getWidth()+5,lblBackup.getHeight()+5);
}                                      

private void lblChangePasswordMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
 lblChangePassword.setSize(lblChangePassword.getWidth()+5,lblChangePassword.getHeight()+5);
}

private void lblAddEmployeeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
 lblAddEmployee.setSize(lblAddEmployee.getWidth()+5,lblAddEmployee.getHeight()+5);
}

private void lblAddCustomerMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
 lblAddCustomer.setSize(lblAddCustomer.getWidth()+5,lblAddCustomer.getHeight()+5);
}
```

Now I want to avoid this repetition of same handler.

Comment: *"Actually i have have to increase the size of JLabel when mouse hovers over it."* That will change the layout of the components, which will sometimes cause the label being pointed to by the mouse, not being the one the user intended (which has moved due to a size increase/decrease earlier in the layout). As such, it is a recipe for an 'unusable GUI'. Please (for the sake of the user) simply change the foreground or background color instead.

Comment: sorry for being a little picky, but this is probably the most minimal indentation i have ever seen. maybe the readability would benefit of some extra spaces. and lines of that length usually benefit some spaces after the comma as well. that looks hell of a lot like german words :D

Answer (score 4):

It's simple -- you can use the same mouse handler class, and can assign it to multiple JLabels, and then get the current involved JLabel via the `MouseEvent#getSource()` method.

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
    // assuming that you only add this MouseListener to JLabels...
    JLabel currentLabel = (JLabel)evt.getSource();

    // do what needs to be done with currentLabel

}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ManyLabelExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDES = 8;
    private static final int GAP = 15;
    public static final Color HOVER_COLOR = Color.pink;
    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    public ManyLabelExample() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));
        MyMouseHandler myMouseHandler = new MyMouseHandler();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIDES * SIDES; i++) {
            String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", i % SIDES + 1, i / SIDES + 1);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
            label.addMouseListener(myMouseHandler);
            labels.add(label);
            add(label);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
            JLabel source = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
            for (JLabel label : labels) {
                if (label == source) {
                    label.setBackground(HOVER_COLOR);
                } else {
                    label.setBackground(null);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ManyLabelExample mainPanel = new ManyLabelExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ManyLabelExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But where should i declare  addMouseListener.I've declared in constructor but its not working

Comment: Heck I've shown you where to declare and use it in the code above.

Comment: `JFrame frame = new JFrame("ManyLabelExample");` I've begun to use the more generic (WTE) `JFrame frame = new JFrame(mainPanel.getClass().getSimpleName());` ..

Comment: oh sorry actually i didn't saw it and thanks for help it worked.

Comment: you did the right thing not to increase the `JLabel`s size, but you could at least have left a remark for the person asking the question that you your code doesn't do exactly what he asked for.. +1 anyways